# how to login a remote host using SSH without a password?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access, sshd, remote-login

SSH server is running at remote host. IP Address of the remote host is known.

Using NMAP command we can see SSH service is running at port 22 which is open.

How to login remote host using ssh client without password?

Example: `ssh root@ip_address`

How to know the user account details such as the number of users present in that remote host and their usernames?

hostname command gives us the name of the host. Is there any command to know the username present within a remote host?

How to execute a linux command on a remote machine without logged in to that remote host?

Comment: This could be illegal.... so I don't know if it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the PKI. 
On the host machines you generate your key-pairs. It will prompt you for default location where to store your:

- public key(extension .pub)
- private key(no extension)

Usually it is in `~/.ssh/` folder. 
    ssh-keygen -t rsa

And use `ssh copy-id` to update your server `authorized_keys`

```
ssh-copy-id root@ip_of_the server
```

---

Alternatively, you can append the contents of your public key `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to the remote host's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: You will need the root password for the `ssh-copy-id` command.

Comment: @user68186 Yep. I assumed he has the access to the remote.

Comment: sorry @fugitive I do not know the root password of remote host.

Comment: @DipankarNalui then - it is not possible. At least in no legitimate way.

Comment: @fugitive is it possible to know the usernames of a remote host ?

Comment: @fugitive is there any other way to login remotely? the remote host is within LAN. I know only the IP Address of that remote hosts.

Comment: @DipankarNalui The content of your question and your comments here appears like you are trying to hack into s computer where you don't have any connection.  That is against the law.  We don't support breaking the law or any other unethical activity on this site.  You would have to communicate with the owner of the site and get the credentials from them to have access.  If they don't give it to you, you should respect their property the same way you would like your home or real property to be respected.

Comment: @fugitive The steps you have provided can only work if the user already has an account on the host to work with.  You steps requires logging in to complete the settings.  He don't have login access.  He's trying to figure out how to get into a system without login access or knowing anything else, but a scan of the network shows an active computer.

Comment: @L.D.James Yes, see my comment above ^ . I didn't read his question carefully while I was responding. :(
DipankarNalui I fully agree with the comment that L.D. James provided to you. Careful with what you are doing.

Comment: @L.D.James I understood that it is not legal. using macchanger command i have a random MAC address. now i am interested to learn how to login remote host without harming it. where from can i learn it. please suggest me.

Comment: Dude, `apt-get install virtualbox` and hack, learn - or whatev'a you're trying to do. Did you know that even a port scanning is illegal in some countries?

Comment: @fugitive I did this using virtual box. But I know the root password of my VirtualBox hosts. without knowing the password how can I login to those hosts?

Answer (score 0):

With login remote host using ssh client without password, I think you can check problems as:

- Permission of file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys after you create and add key id_rsa.pub to file(Ex: User root --> file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys), but when you create file maybe it have permission is: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 test1 test1    4 Aug  9 11:19 authorized_keys`. After you change permission 600 for file with command: `chmod -R 600 authorized_keys`.

Check permission user root in file `/etc/sudoers`. You can add option `NOPASSWD` for user or group in file with line:

- For a single user: `root   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`
- For a group : `%supergroup  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

In Firewall I think you can open and allow IP Remote to port 22.

```
ufw allow from [IP Remote]  to any port 22
```

or

```
ufw allow from any to any port 22
```

I hope it help you remote without password.

Answer (score 0):

You should not ask these questions here, log in without permissions are forbidden. Nevertheless at the level of your question is quite very beginner level so hacking would out of discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH-key, then do the following steps, but before that you should configure your SSH-Server configuration

Disable password login

```bsh
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

in `sshd_config` code edit this lines of code

```
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitRootLogin no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

now, password login for root and other users is disabled, after this restart your sshd server

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

you can do this directly

```bsh
ssh-copy-id root@ip_of_the server
```

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

---

Or

Now you should in you home directory, for examole `/home/your-username` create `.ssh` folder and inside `.ssh` folder create `authorized_keys` file, follow this commands

```bsh
$ cd /home/your-username
$ mkdir .ssh
$ sudo nano .ssh/authorized_keys  ## Paste your public key here
$ ctrl + p
$ ctrl + x
```

Now you should set the permission and owner for `.ssh` & `authorized_keys`

`.ssh`

```bsh
$ sudo chmod 700 .ssh
$ sudo chown your-username:your-username .ssh
```

`authorized_keys`

```bsh
$ cd .ssh
$ sudo chmod 700 authorized_keys
$ sudo chown your-username:your-username authorized_keys
```

until here we are finish and it should work, to apply this configuration you should first of all restart your SSH

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Finish! Done!